# .NET CORE 2.1. Issue posting from one Docker container to another by HTTPS

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have 2 docker apps, both .NET Core, on Linux containers(Windows is a host), which need to talk: one, let's called it First, posting data to another one, let's call it Second. Both use kestrel.
Under Docker I've created (using docker network command) a network, so those two apps could talk to each other.

I am using Visual Studio 2017 for debugging.
I create console app to start communication. This app posting data to First docker app, 
which does some massaging and posts to Second docker app to get some love.

Up to the point of posting from First app to Second everything is going well, but during posting I see strange errors, which I could not decipher.

Here how I create WebHost instance for Second app, which receives posts:

```
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseKestrel(kestrelOptions =>
        {
            kestrelOptions.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(m=>
            {
                m.SslProtocols |= System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls11 | System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12;
            });
        })
        .UseUrls("http://*:44348", "http://*:443") // listen on all network interfaces
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Here is how First does posting, where httpClient is of HttpClient type:

```
        StringContent content = new StringContent($"{{\"field1\" : \"{obj.Field1}\", \"field2\":\"{obj.Field2}\"}}"
                                                    , Encoding.UTF8
                                                    , "application/json");
        var response = httpClient.PostAsync("Test\\Log", content)?
                                            .GetAwaiter()
                                            .GetResult();
```

Here is full url of posting:https://172.19.0.2:44348/api/Test/Log, where specified ip address is node ip address in Docker network I've created.

> It looks like there is attempt to send https request over http,
>   because if I remove "EXPOSE 80" from Dockerfile below First app gets
>   "No route to host" message back.

Here is Dockerfile of Second app:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 44348

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Second.csproj" "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "/Second.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/
RUN dotnet build "Second.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Second.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Second.dll"]
```

This is what First app gets(sending side):

> Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' in
>   System.Private.CoreLib.dll System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 
>   The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. ---> 
>   System.IO.IOException: The handshake failed due to an unexpected
>   packet format.
>   at 
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.PartialFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest
>   asyncRequest)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at System.Net.Security.SslState.ThrowIfExceptional()
>   at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult
>   lazyResult)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult
>   result)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.b__47_1(IAsyncResult
>   iar)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult
>   iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean
>   requiresSynchronization)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream
>   stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream
>   stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()    at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()    at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync(ValueTask`1
>   creationTask)    at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
>   at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Http.Logging.LoggingScopeHttpMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask,
>   HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean
>   disposeCts)

And these beauties Second app gets(receiving side):

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException:
>   Invalid request line:
>   '\x16\x03\x01\x019\x01\x00\x015\x03\x03>~\x0C\xDAl2\xD9\xDC\xB5*\xD5\x95\x8D\xC000\x8Aa\xE6\xC3\xF7\xE9\xA1&<\xF8\x02[\x90U\xA3\x0E\x00\x00\xA2\xC00\xC0,\xC0(\xC0$\xC0\x14\xC0\x0A'
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpParser`1.RejectRequestLine(Byte*
>   requestLine, Int32 length)  at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpParser`1.GetUnknownMethod(Byte*
>   data, Int32 length, Int32& methodLength) at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpParser`1.ParseRequestLine(TRequestHandler
>   handler, Byte* data, Int32 length)  at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpParser`1.ParseRequestLine(TRequestHandler
>   handler, ReadOnlySequence`1& buffer, SequencePosition& consumed,
>   SequencePosition& examined)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpParser`1.Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.IHttpParser.ParseRequestLine(TRequestHandler
>   handler, ReadOnlySequence`1& buffer, SequencePosition& consumed,
>   SequencePosition& examined)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1Connection.TakeStartLine(ReadOnlySequence`1 buffer, SequencePosition& consumed, SequencePosition& examined) at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1Connection.ParseRequest(ReadOnlySequence`1 buffer, SequencePosition& consumed, SequencePosition& examined)  at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1Connection.TryParseRequest(ReadResult result, Boolean& endConnection) at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1
>   application) at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1
>   application) [20:43:37 INF] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel:
>   Connection id "0HLIRMJN7758A" bad request data: "Invalid request line:
>   '\x16\x03\x01\x019\x01\x00\x015\x03\x03>~\x0C\xDAl2\xD9\xDC\xB5*\xD5\x95\x8D\xC000\x8Aa\xE6\xC3\xF7\xE9\xA1&<\xF8\x02[\x90U\xA3\x0E\x00\x00\xA2\xC00\xC0,\xC0(\xC0$\xC0\x14\xC0\x0A'"
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException:
>   Invalid request line:
>   '\x16\x03\x01\x019\x01\x00\x015\x03\x03>~\x0C\xDAl2\xD9\xDC\xB5*\xD5\x95\x8D\xC000\x8Aa\xE6\xC3\xF7\xE9\xA1&<\xF8\x02[\x90U\xA3\x0E\x00\x00\xA2\xC00\xC0,\xC0(\xC0$\xC0\x14\xC0\x0A'
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpParser`1.RejectRequestLine(Byte* requestLine, Int32 length)  at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpParser`1.GetUnknownMethod(Byte* data, Int32 length, Int32& methodLength)   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpParser`1.ParseRequestLine(TRequestHandler
>   handler, Byte* data, Int32 length)   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpParser`1.ParseRequestLine(TRequestHandler
>   handler, ReadOnlySequence`1& buffer, SequencePosition& consumed,
>   SequencePosition& examined)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpParser`1.Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.IHttpParser<TRequestHandler>.ParseRequestLine(TRequestHandler
>   handler, ReadOnlySequence`1& buffer, SequencePosition& consumed,
>   SequencePosition& examined)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1Connection.TakeStartLine(ReadOnlySequence`1 buffer, SequencePosition& consumed, SequencePosition& examined)  at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1Connection.ParseRequest(ReadOnlySequence`1
>   buffer, SequencePosition& consumed, SequencePosition& examined)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1Connection.TryParseRequest(ReadResult result, Boolean& endConnection)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequestsAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1
>   application) [41m[30mfail[39m[22m[49m:
>   JDBJwtToken.Middlewares.BadRequestDiagnosticAdapter[0]
>         Observed 400 response. The last 318 bytes of request data were: 
>         [HEX] 16 03 01 01 39 01 00 01 35 03 03 3E 7E 0C DA 6C 32 D9 DC B5 2A D5 95 8D C0 30 30 8A 61 E6 C3 F7 E9 A1 26 3C F8 02 5B 90 55 A3
>   0E 00 00 A2 C0 30 C0 2C C0 28 C0 24 C0 14 C0 0A 00 A5 00 A3 00 A1 00
>   9F 00 6B 00 6A 00 69 00 68 00 39 00 38 00 37 00 36 00 88 00 87 00 86
>   00 85 C0 19 00 A7 00 6D 00 3A 00 89 C0 32 C0 2E C0 2A C0 26 C0 0F C0
>   05 00 9D 00 3D 00 35 00 84 C0 2F C0 2B C0 27 C0 23 C0 13 C0 09 00 A4
>   00 A2 00 A0 00 9E 00 67 00 40 00 3F 00 3E 00 33 00 32 00 31 00 30 00
>   9A 00 99 00 98 00 97 00 45 00 44 00 43 00 42 C0 18 00 A6 00 6C 00 34
>   00 9B 00 46 C0 31 C0 2D C0 29 C0 25 C0 0E C0 04 00 9C 00 3C 00 2F 00
>   96 00 41 00 FF 01 00 00 6A 00 00 00 11 00 0F 00 00 0C 39 36 30 37 32
>   37 33 38 34 65 35 39 00 0B 00 04 03 00 01 02 00 0A 00 1C 00 1A 00 17
>   00 19 00 1C 00 1B 00 18 00 1A 00 16 00 0E 00 0D 00 0B 00 0C 00 09 00
>   0A 00 23 00 00 00 0D 00 20 00 1E 06 01 06 02 06 03 05 01 05 02 05 03
>   04 01 04 02 04 03 03 01 03 02 03 03 02 01 02 02 02 03 00 0F 00 01 01
>
> [RAW] 9?5>~Úl2ÙÜµ*ÕÀ00aæÃ÷é¡&<ø[U£??¢À0À,À(À$ÀÀ
>         ?¥?£?¡??k?j?i?h?9?8?7?6???? À?§?m?:?À2À.À*À&ÀÀ??=?5?À/À+À'À#ÀÀ   ?¤?¢? ??g?@???>?3?2?1?0?????E?D?C?BÀ?¦?l?4??FÀ1À-À)À%ÀÀ??
>   [HEX] 16 03 01
>   01 39 01 00 01 35 03 03 3E 7E 0C DA 6C 32 D9 DC B5 2A D5 95 8D C0 30
>   30 8A 61 E6 C3 F7 E9 A1 26 3C F8 02 5B 90 55 A3 0E 00 00 A2 C0 30 C0
>   2C C0 28 C0 24 C0 14 C0 0A 00 A5 00 A3 00 A1 00 9F 00 6B 00 6A 00 69
>   00 68 00 39 00 38 00 37 00 36 00 88 00 87 00 86 00 85 C0 19 00 A7 00
>   6D 00 3A 00 89 C0 32 C0 2E C0 2A C0 26 C0 0F C0 05 00 9D 00 3D 00 35
>   00 84 C0 2F C0 2B C0 27 C0 23 C0 13 C0 09 00 A4 00 A2 00 A0 00 9E 00
>   67 00 40 00 3F 00 3E 00 33 00 32 00 31 00 30 00 9A 00 99 00 98 00 97
>   00 45 00 44 00 43 00 42 C0 18 00 A6 00 6C 00 34 00 9B 00 46 C0 31 C0
>   2D C0 29 C0 25 C0 0E C0 04 00 9C 00 3C 00 2F 00 96 00 41 00 FF 01 00
>   00 6A 00 00 00 11 00 0F 00 00 0C 39 36 30 37 32 37 33 38 34 65 35 39
>   00 0B 00 04 03 00 01 02 00 0A 00 1C 00 1A 00 17 00 19 00 1C 00 1B 00
>   18 00 1A 00 16 00 0E 00 0D 00 0B 00 0C 00 09 00 0A 00 23 00 00 00 0D
>   00 20 00 1E 06 01 06 02 06 03 05 01 05 02 05 03 04 01 04 02 04 03 03
>   01 03 02 03 03 02 01 02 02 02 03 00 0F 00 01 01
>   [RAW] 9
>   [20:43:37 ERR] JDBJwtToken.Middlewares.BadRequestDiagnosticAdapter:
>   Observed 400 response. The last 318 bytes of request data were:
>   [HEX]
>   16 03 01 01 39 01 00 01 35 03 03 3E 7E 0C DA 6C 32 D9 DC B5 2A D5 95
>   8D C0 30 30 8A 61 E6 C3 F7 E9 A1 26 3C F8 02 5B 90 55 A3 0E 00 00 A2
>   C0 30 C0 2C C0 28 C0 24 C0 14 C0 0A 00 A5 00 A3 00 A1 00 9F 00 6B 00
>   6A 00 69 00 68 00 39 00 38 00 37 00 36 00 88 00 87 00 86 00 85 C0 19
>   00 A7 00 6D 00 3A 00 89 C0 32 C0 2E C0 2A C0 26 C0 0F C0 05 00 9D 00
>   3D 00 35 00 84 C0 2F C0 2B C0 27 C0 23 C0 13 C0 09 00 A4 00 A2 00 A0
>   00 9E 00 67 00 40 00 3F 00 3E 00 33 00 32 00 31 00 30 00 9A 00 99 00
>   98 00 97 00 45 00 44 00 43 00 42 C0 18 00 A6 00 6C 00 34 00 9B 00 46
>   C0 31 C0 2D C0 29 C0 25 C0 0E C0 04 00 9C 00 3C 00 2F 00 96 00 41 00
>   FF 01 00 00 6A 00 00 00 11 00 0F 00 00 0C 39 36 30 37 32 37 33 38 34
>   65 35 39 00 0B 00 04 03 00 01 02 00 0A 00 1C 00 1A 00 17 00 19 00 1C
>   00 1B 00 18 00 1A 00 16 00 0E 00 0D 00 0B 00 0C 00 09 00 0A 00 23 00
>   00 00 0D 00 20 00 1E 06 01 06 02 06 03 05 01 05 02 05 03 04 01 04 02
>   04 03 03 01 03 02 03 03 02 01 02 02 02 03 00 0F 00 01 01
>   [RAW]
>   9?5>~Úl2ÙÜµ*ÕÀ00aæÃ÷é¡&<ø[U£??¢À0À,À(À$ÀÀ
>   ?¥?£?¡??k?j?i?h?9?8?7?6????
>   À?§?m?:?À2À.À*À&ÀÀ??=?5?À/À+À'À#ÀÀ ?¤?¢? ??g?@???>?3?2?1?0?????E?D?C?BÀ?¦?l?4??FÀ1À-À)À%ÀÀ??

If somedody whould be able to get me some hints how to resolve this situation, I would be very appriciative.

Comment: Your app is listening on `HTTP` protocol only, see here: `.UseUrls("http://*:44348", "http://*:443") // listen on all network interfaces`

When you are posting to it, change url to `http://172.19.0.2:44348/api/Test/Log`, it will work. Note: that is insecure. To configure Kestrel to use certificate you need to pass it in using ` listenOptions.UseHttps(certificate);`, see here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/11/29/configuring-https-in-asp-net-core-across-different-platforms/

Comment: @zaitsman Thanks, man! You are right!Works now. If u'll make it answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app is listening on HTTP protocol only, see here:

```
.UseUrls("http://*:44348", "http://*:443") // listen on all network interfaces
```

When you are posting to it, change url to `http://172.19.0.2:44348/api/Test/Log`, it will work.

> Note: that is insecure.

To configure Kestrel to use certificate you need to pass it in using `listenOptions.UseHttps(certificate);`, see here for more info:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/11/29/configuring-https-in-asp-net-core-across-different-platforms/